# true wireless ear bud that has it all

Tags: wireless, earphones

I'm looking for a pair of true wireless earbuds that I can use with my (Linux) PC and my Android (Pixel 3) phone.  Money is no object, but having all the features I need is a must.

- CVC 8.0 noise reduction for clear calls outdoors and in windy environments.
- Active and Passive Noise cancellation that can be switched off with a pass through of ambient sounds if desired.  Strangely, a lot of earbuds omit one or both.
- A rating of at least IP54
- low headset latency is highly preferred so for instance if I'm gaming the sound is not out of sync with the screen.  Apt-X (e.g. Qualcomm 3020) is the technical spec I seem to need here.
- Google Assistant integration.  I believe this rules out stuff like Apple's Airpod Pros
- I need to be able to pair with both my PC and my phone without hassle switching between them.  It seems like a lot of earbuds do this

Here's issues I have found with earbuds I have researched so far. Note that for some devices I have no data on whether they meet certain requirements:

Sennheiser Momentum True Wireless 2 - doesn't support hassle free pairing with multiple devices, has excessive latency (300ms)

Google Pixel Buds (2020) - no active noise cancellation

Sony WF-1000XM3 - no IPX rating

Jabra Elite Active 75t - no active noise cancellation

Huawei Freebuds 3 and Huawei Freebuds 3i - the noise cancellation seems to be lacking on the 3 model, while the 3i is inferior to the 3 in many of the specs.

Boltune BT-BH023 and BT-BH024 - the first has ANC but not CVC 8.0, the second has CVC 8.0 but not ANC!

Mifo O7 - has CVC 8.0 but not ANC

Bluedio Fi - has CVC 8.0 but not ANC